# Django request.DATA gets corrupt value

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-rest-framework

My problem

My problem is that when sending a json document via post to a rest framework api, the document converts a key and adds an empty value.

file.js

```
function SaveFiles(task_id) {
     data = {'taskid': task_id,'file_list': file_list};
     $.ajax({
        url: '/tarjet/save.../',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async:false,
        success:function(data){

        },
        complete:function(){},
        error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){

        }
    });
```

}

api.py

```
class SaveTaskFiles(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request):
        a = request.DATA
```

javascript output

```
{"taskid":"1198792","file_list":[{"id":0,"file_name":"image2.png","upload_date":"11/16/2016","file_description":"","download_link":"a6175ab4-ac58-11e6-8e10-00dbdfd54837.png","isdeactivate":"0","sft_f":"svt"}]}
```

actual input request.DATA

```
{u'{"taskid":"1198792","file_list":[{"id":0,"file_name":"image2.png","upload_date":"11/16/2016","file_description":"","download_link":"a6175ab4-ac58-11e6-8e10-00dbdfd54837.png","isdeactivate":"0","sft_f":"svt"}]}': [u'']}
```

Is a Querydict type.

I can not explain why my json file becomes a key,and this value is a empty list, i have solved it using request.body, but I know it's not the convention. I've tried dumps, loads, but it did not work, although I could get the key and use it, I do not think that's a good idea.

Beforehand thank you very much ¡

Comment: You're aware that your ajax is sending a json string, right?

Comment: @RodXavier, Yes, I tried with JSON.stringify, without this too, with parseJSON, with $.post, and i get the same request.DATA.

Comment: Try posting same json using curl or another tool, and see if this problem on backend or on frontend side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the correct content-type header to tell DRF that you are sending a JSON document, not a plain string.

```
 $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/json',
      ...
 });
```

See the [DRF parsers docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/).